# How can a controller or route send an action to itself

Tags: ember.js

Given the following code, how can the route call it's `doSomething` action?

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // call the doSomething action
  },
  actions: {
    doSomething: function() { ... }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Transition` object which is passed do `beforeModel`/`model`/`afterModel` hook.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    doSomething() {
      console.log('doSomethingInvoked');
    }
  },
  beforeModel(transition) {
    transition.send('doSomething');
  },
  model(params, transition) {
    transition.send('doSomething');
  },
  afterModel(model, transition) {
    transition.send('doSomething');
  }
});
```

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lamedemoni/3/edit)